# Как сделать выборку меток всех постов, исключая все повторения в WP?

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать выборку меток всех постов, исключая все повторения? Мне нужно, чтобы выводилась 1 или несколько поисковых подсказок, а сейчас выводится равное количеству постов. Как поправить? Сейчас код имеет такой вид:

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue jQuery UI and autocomplete
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-autocomplete' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

function theme_autocomplete_js() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'   => -1 // all posts
    );

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

        if( $posts ) :
            foreach( $posts as $k => $post ) {
                $source[$k]['ID'] = $post->ID;
                $tags = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'portfolio_entries');
                foreach($tags as $tag){
                    $tags_array[] = $tag->name;
                    //$tags_array = array_unique($tags_array);
                }
                $tags_array = array_unique($tags_array, SORT_REGULAR);
                $comma_separated_tags = implode( ', ' , $tags_array);
                $source[$k]['label'] = $comma_separated_tags;//$post->post_title; // The name of the post
                $source[$k]['permalink'] = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            }

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var posts = <?php echo json_encode( array_values( $source ) ); ?>;

            jQuery( '#s' ).autocomplete({
                source: posts,
                minLength: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    var permalink = ui.item.permalink; // Get permalink from the datasource

                    window.location.replace(permalink);
                }
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'theme_autocomplete_js' );
```

Вот результат вывода:
[image]

В живую попробовать [тут](https://israel-escorts.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Для вывода меток совершенно необязательно перебирать все посты (что медленно). Используйте функцию `wp_tag_cloud()` - она выведет облако меток, с ограничением по количеству, со ссылками на эти метки, с разным размером шрифта в зависимости от частоты использования меток.

Выглядит это примерно так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробности на русском [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_tag_cloud).

Comment: с этой функцией у меня вообще не работает, обновил код в вопросе, сейчас результат лучше, но еще не то, что нужно.

Comment: @spoilt если "не работает" значит что-то не от делаешь. Это правильное решение в отличии от `get_posts` для вывода меток.

Comment: @SeVlad мне не нужно их выводить, просто список всех меток сохранить в массив для кастомных типов записей

Comment: @spoilt, а описание функции ниасилилил? Ну и кроме это есть и др. `get_tags`  напр.